# Getting users to verify their accounts through Instagram Biography

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I am trying to add a way to let users enter a code in their biography which I'd then fetch from my backend and check whether or not their bio contains the code or not. (Some apps are doing this already), the problem is, I was gonna use [Business discovery for this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/business_discovery) it seems to be the only way without Facebook login to access their biography with just a username. The issue is that this endpoint also requires an access token, so what access token do I use? Can I just use my own access token and get information of potentionally thousands of users? Won't this get me banned or ip banned? Is there some other way these apps achieve this

Comment: A user access token ... just like the page you linked to says.

Comment: @CBroe I am not asking that, these services aren't asking for a login to get the user access token and can still access the biography, you can see here https://influencer.influry.com/signup  . I am trying to avoid using the Facebook login